# How to restore default function in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I changed beep function `(defun beep () ...`, is it possible to revert it without restarting Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visit the original definition, and evaluate it.

If need be you can start a second instance of Emacs in order to find the code: `C-h f beep RET` and follow the link to the source code.

(I'd normally say `find-function`, but in this instance beep is an alias, and following the link takes you to the `defalias` line, whereas find-function goes to the source definition.)

Comment: the doc show my new function in `.emacs` and I can't find it in source code I've try `find + xargs` search.

Comment: That's why I suggested starting a *second* instance of Emacs, so that you can ask it where that function *normally* lives. Then you can switch back to your modified instance to make the change.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you first saved `(symbol-function 'ding)`.  If you did, then you can restore it (using `fset`).  If not, you cannot, because `ding` (aka `beep`) is defined in C, not Lisp.

If it were defined in Lisp then you could do what @phils suggested.

Comment: Ah, but `beep` is an alias, so it can be restored to an alias. Its function cell usually just contains `ding` (symbol function indirection) and so is independent of `ding` itself. (If it were `ding` which had been redefined, OTOH, you'd certainly be stuck).

Comment: Good point - right you are, @phils.  OP: you should choose phils's answer: just reevaluate the `defalias` for `beep`, to give it again the behavior of `ding`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a fluke, but I can do it currently with:

```
(defun restore-redefined-function (name)
  (interactive (find-function-read))
  (save-window-excursion
    (find-function name)
    (eval-defun nil)))
```

1. In `*scratch*`:

   ```
   (defun beep () "foo")
   ;; beep

   (symbol-function 'beep)
   ;; (lambda nil "foo")
   ```
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `restore-redefined-function` and enter `beep`.
3. in `*scratch*`:

   ```
   (symbol-function 'beep)
   ;; ding
   ```

Comment: try just `(find-function 'beep)`

Comment: Tested with `emacs -q`. Version 24.3.50.1 and 24.3.4